# java Cant retrieve the data from sql server in my jtable

Tags: java

//i get all this connection errors.... i guess i miss something thats why this mess happends .i am new with this so if enyone can help :D

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Suppliers'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:786)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:685)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:620)
    at mylogin.Suppliers.getuserList(Suppliers.java:61)
    at mylogin.Suppliers.show_suppliers_in_Jtable(Suppliers.java:75)
    at mylogin.Suppliers.<init>(Suppliers.java:30)
    at mylogin.Suppliers$6.run(Suppliers.java:345)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

public class Suppliers extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
    /**
     * Creates new form Suppliers
     */
    public Suppliers() {
        initComponents();
        show_suppliers_in_Jtable();
    }
     String driver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1435;databaseName=supermarket";
     String user ="sa";
     String pass ="sql!123";


     public Connection getConnection()
     {
         Connection con;
      try {
         Class.forName(driver);  
         con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
         return con;
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       }

     }
     public ArrayList<Update_del_insert> getuserList()
     {
         ArrayList <Update_del_insert> userList =new ArrayList <Update_del_insert> ();
         Connection connection =getConnection();

         String query ="SELECT * FROM 'Suppliers'";
         Statement st;
         ResultSet rs;
         try{
            st = connection.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            Update_del_insert  update_del_insert ;
            while(rs.next())
            {
               update_del_insert = new Update_del_insert (rs.getString("SupName"),rs.getString("SupSurName"));
               userList.add(update_del_insert);
            }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         return userList;
     } 
     //display data in jtable
     public void show_suppliers_in_Jtable(){
         ArrayList<Update_del_insert> list= getuserList();
         DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)jtable_Suppliers.getModel();
         Object[] row =new Object[2];
         for(int i =0;i< list.size();i++)
         {
             row[0] = list.get(i).getsupName();
             row[1] = list.get(i).getsupSurName();

             model.addRow(row);

         }

}
```

//SupName and SupSurName are my tables on sql

```
public class Update_del_insert {
    private String SupName;
    private String SupSurName;
    public Update_del_insert(String supName,String supSurName )
    {
        this.SupName=supName;
        this.SupSurName=supSurName;
    }

    public String getsupName()
    {
        return SupName;
    }
     public String getsupSurName()
    {
        return SupSurName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM 'Suppliers'";
```

with this

```
String query ="SELECT * FROM Suppliers";
```

You dont need to (') in your select

Comment: So not for your reputation then? :-p

Comment: TWO IN ONE @Adriaan Koster